# git remove file starting with a colon

Tags: git, unix, filenames

I accidentally created a file named `:w`. I managed to delete it by using zsh tab feature. But I cannot remove it from my git cache.

```
    git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   Gemfile
#   modified:   Gemfile.lock
#   new file:   config/newrelic.yml
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    :w
#
```

then

```
git rm :w
fatal: pathspec 'w' did not match any files
```

Comment: did you try : `git rm --cached -r .` ??

Comment: Ha! Thank you for this question and answer. Let me guess, you use Vim and somehow typed ":w", then maybe the mind wandered a bit and you typed ":w" again. I think it would have taken me more than the 1 minute (way <5 minutes, I might add!) it took you to find the solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

found the answer not 5 minutes later

```
git rm '\:w'
```

Comment: works for starting with other unhelpful characters as well, like a dash.